# Simulating the significance level of a t-test in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

The following code generates 10000 t-tests on a custom distribution I have created.

```
> x <- replicate(10000,{  
  t.test(rcn(20,.25,25), mu=0, alternative="greater")
  })
```

I am constructing an empirical level of significance and so I am interested in the number of test-statistics that are greather than the critical value of the respective t-distribution, which is 1.729 (for a t-distribution with 19 degrees of freedom).

How can I select (and count) these test-statistics here? The ratio of their number over 10000, the total number of simulations, will give me my empirical level of significance.

Comment: please make your example reproducible by giving the definition of `rcn`.

Comment: @Beasterfield My question stands for any distribution. How do I select the t-tests that have some identical characteristic amongst thousands? Thank you.

Comment: I understood that, but then you could have chosen a distribution function from `stats` giving people the opportunity to just copy past your code. Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the test statistic of each `t.test` in `replicate`. For example:

```
x <- replicate(10000, {
 t.test(rcn(20,.25,25), mu=0, alternative="greater")$statistic
})
```

This returns a vector of t-values.

You can compare it with your critical value and count the `TRUE`s:

```
crit <- 1.729
sum(x > crit)
```

Comment: Nice! Is that what the dollar symbol does? It refines the function?

Comment: @JohnK `$` is used to access an element. In this case `t.test` returns a list. The `$` symbol extracts the element with the name `statistic`.